# How to uninstall blender

Tags: installation

From the control panel, I click on Blender and right-click to uninstall.

Getting this pop-up

[image]

How to uninstall old version 2.79 complete blender version from pc.

Any suggestion or help. Im using win7.

Comment: It should be in the list under Control Panel > Programs and Features assuming it was installed in the conventional way unless the installation method was different for 2.79? Just click on the Blender entry in the list and then hit Uninstall from the menu. If it was installed as a portable version you can simply delete the folder it's in.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes i have deleted the folder but how to remove or uninstall it from the control panel list

Comment: We're getting off topic and away from Blender-related questions here but see [this](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/remove-program-from-add-remove/) page for how to remove an entry from the list. Be **very** careful if you're not familiar with the Registry! A quick tip to find the correct entry among all the unintelligible entries is to hilight the main 'Uninstall' folder, press F3 and search for 'Blender' to find the right entry to delete.